# How would I fix this arduino code so that the LEDs are lit up from the last LEDs?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, reverse, led

I followed a tutorial and I got everything to work, but I want to send waves out from the last LED instead of the first.

Here's the original code:
https://github.com/justcallmekoko/Arduino-FastLED-Music-Visualizer/blob/master/music_visualizer.ino

Here's what my LED strip looks like right now - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyXfUG3vxJ0

Sorry, I'm so lost. I'm very new to coding.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [example]. Please ask a specific programming question. Please include all relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The stuff you are looking for is done into the `rainbow` function
You need to reverse how `leds` array is filled, `leds` is filled from `0` to `react`, you need to fill from `NUM_LEDS - react` to `NUM_LEDS`

Try something like:

```
void rainbow()
{
  for(int i = NUM_LEDS; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i <= react)
      leds[NUM_LEDS - i] = Scroll((i * 256 / 50 + k) % 256);
    else
      leds[NUM_LEDS - i] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);      
  }
  FastLED.show(); 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the second `leds[i]` need to be updated too?

Comment: Thank you both! I got it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIdjawplPJQ

Comment: oops thanks @CherryDT, update done